# How to create a Dojo store from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo, dgrid

I am new to Dojo Frame work, so please do bear with me.
I have a service implemented in a way that it will return  JSON response . 
I am using Dojo frame work for UI. I am not sure about the right way to request to server and get the response in dojo.

I found 3 ways to request to server and receiving response.am not sure whether it's wrong or even remotely right

1)

```
request(contextName+"/service/getquestions/projectId/"+projectId,{
                    handleAs: "json"
                    }).then(function(data){alert("something")});
```

2)

```
var questionAnswerStore = new JsonRest({
                        target: contextName+"/service/getquestions/projectId/"+projectId,
                                       });
```

3)

```
request.get("contextName+"/service/getquestions/projectId/"+projectId",{
    handleAs: "json"
}).then(function(data){
    dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore:new Memory({ data: data.items }) });
        });
```

Further, the store created will be used to populate the dgrid elements.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When working with widgets you should wrap your data in a `dojo/store`. That leaves out your first method.

The second one, like @PaulR told you, is the best approach. But it also means your REST service should follow certain rules which you can find at their [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#implementing-a-rest-server).
If you cannot meet these standards, you can choose to extend the `dojo/store/JsonRest` module so you can make it conform or you use the third method.

The third method is probably the easiest if your REST service is not compliant with the requirements. You do not need to use the `dojo/data/ObjectStore` adapter in the new versions of Dojo, since all widget stores should be using the `dojo/store` API now (and not the old `dojo/data` API).

Comment: Thanx buddy. To make the context clear, I am simply developing an HTML page that will be populating the grid using the resposne. But when i use the second method as exactly in the snipplte, It gets me an error in my chrome console as "Uncaught typeError: object is not a function".This is a common javascript error, but i couldn't figure out the reason. JsonRest is being included in the function. Also is there any other extra attribute to be included within in the JsonRest constructor other than 'target' ?

Comment: Also, one thing i would to like to ask, by simply giving the complete request URL in the target attribute of JsonRest, will I be able to get the store that could be used as normal dataStore declared within the require method ?

Comment: According to the documentation, an object with a target property should be sufficient. But if your sole purpose is to render the data (no insert/update/delete), I think the third approach will be easier to you.

Answer (score 0):

The second way is the "best" one; Dojo is [modeled on](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store.html) the Store interface for retrieving and manipulating (server-side) data.
The other ways may not be wrong, but are not the "Dojo way" of using a REST interface.

The target parameter should contain the rest endpoint (/service/getquestions/projectId). When you want to retrieve information for a specific project, you would call store.get(projectId) on the store which would then perform a GET request to /service/getquestions/projectId/projectid and return the appropriate data.

In the same way an update can be done by calling store.put(object), which will do a PUT request on  /service/getquestions/projectId/projectid.

Hope this helps. If not, more information on stores can be found [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store.html).

Comment: Thanx buddy. To make the context clear, I am simply developing an HTML page that will be populating the grid using the resposne. But when i use the second method as exactly in the snipplte, It gets me  an error in my chrome console as "Uncaught typeError: object is not a function".This is a common javascript error, but i couldn't figure out the reason. JsonRest is being included in the function.  Also is there any other extra attribute to be included within in the JsonRest constructor other than 'target' ?

Comment: Are you using the [Dojo source](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.2/dojo-release-1.9.2-src.zip) for developing? This can really help track down an error such as this.

Comment: yes @PaulR, Using dojo-release-1.9.2 but still the error persists.

Comment: solved that issue by using {new dojo.store.JsonRest} instead of just {new JsonRest}.Although, i was specifying it both in require and the immediate function. Now that i have new issues. The "contextName" is being appended in the target URL twice. and the parameter "projectId" is also appended twice. I tried removing em one by one. When i removed the "contextName", it is gone. But when i remove "projectId", a value '1' is automatically being appended at the end. Is there any particular syntax that i should follow to specify these context name and parameters for the URL ?